# How to get all rows from last inserted date in a table?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

So, if I do an insert everyday, how do I get the latest rows of data that correspond to the latest date from Postgresql using SQlAlchemy?

Answer (score 2):

Do this with two queries.  First get the latest date.  Then get the rows with that date.  Here's an example where the `Item` model has an `updated` date column.

```
latest = session.query(func.max(Item.updated)).scalar()
items = session.query(Item).filter_by(updated=latest).all()
```